# How to mock jdbctemplate query with beanpropertyrowmapper?

Tags: java, sql, mockito, repository, rowmapper

question, how can i mock this method ?

```
return jdbcTemplate.query(query.toString(), new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(TarjetaCoordenada.class), id);

@Override
    public <T> List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper, @Nullable Object... args) throws DataAccessException {
        return result(query(sql, args, new RowMapperResultSetExtractor<>(rowMapper)));
    }
```

This is my current code, all i need to do is find out how to mock the JDBC query method with the arguments above.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TipoEstadoRepositoryTests {
    
    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private TipoEstadoRepository repository;
    
    @Test
    void shouldValidateConsultar() {
        when(repository.consultar(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(null);
        Assertions.assertNull(repository.consultar("abc"));
    }

}
```

Comment: I did not understand what method are you referring to. The static method singleResult or the jdbcTemplate.query one?

Comment: The jdbctemplate query one.

Comment: Are you trying to mock it in a unit test? Can you share your current code? Just want to know if you are using Mockito for example and how are you using it.

Comment: There's my current code, updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
when(jdbcTemplate.query(yourQuery, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(TarjetaCoordenada.class), yourId)).thenReturn(yourResult)
```

Or:

```
when(jdbcTemplate.query(eq(yourQuery), any(), eq(yourId))).thenReturn(yourResult)
```

Replace **yourQuery**, **yourId** and **yourResult** with the expected test values.